# Coloring a String according to character weights

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a string in python like
`text = "hello world"`
and then I have a list containing a weight for each character of the string
`weights = [25,23,51,60,11,32,34,95,4,3,55]`.
Now I want to get a figure showing the string and it's background colored according to the characters weights (like a colormap that visualizes the character's weights).
How can I do that with Python (matplotlib)?

I should look similar to this:
[image]

The characters could also be below the colorfields (as kind of label).

## SOLUTION:

I got it working the following way now

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.set_cmap(plt.cm.autumn) 

weights = [[1, 6, 3, 10, 8, 3, 2, 5]]
ax.imshow(weights, interpolation='none')
ax.text(0, 0, "h")
ax.text(1, 0, "e")
ax.text(2, 0, "l")
ax.text(3, 0, "l")
ax.text(4, 0, "o")
ax.text(5, 0, " ")
ax.text(5, 0, "w")
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snipped that I found somewhere on SO that uses continuous colors of a chosen color map for plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet_r') #or other color map
multiplicators = np.linspace(1,10)
x = np.linspace(1,10)
for idx, item in enumerate(multiplicators):
    color = cmap(idx/len(multiplicators))
    ax.plot(x, x*item, color=color)
```

In a similar way you could color-code your weights by saying

```
color = cmap(word_weight/max_weight)
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was not what I was looking for. I added a picture to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Of course this is not a full solution to your question. It only shows a way how to get a color from a colormap for each weight. You can then print for example each letter using `plt.text(x, y, "H", backgroundcolor=color)`.